# "packet delivery ratio" in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I simulte highway scenario and vehicles movin using sumo  how to get network packets simulation and obtain performance metrics such as "packet delivery ratio" , etc.? relevant performance metrics need to be measured and how to get them from code
how to get network packets simulation and obtain performance metrics such as "packet delivery ratio" ,

what relevant performance metrics need to be measured and how to get them from code

Comment: This site focuses on fixing issues with code.  If you could show where you've got to you're more likely to get useful answers.  As a language comment, I'm concerned about your use of the term "packet".  Do you mean like a TCP/IP network packet, or a physical package being delivered by vehicles in a road network.